# How to do sorting and select distinct in mogodb php query

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting, distinct

i have a mongo php query with aggregate frame work, now i want to add sorting and select distinct criteria to that query, please not that my query is working perfectly without these two criterias,

take a look

```
$result = $collection->aggregate(array(
array(
'$match' => array(

  'Details.Model' =>"AUDI",
  'Details.Color' => "RED",
  "Category" =>"Car"

    )
  ),
 array(
'$unwind' => '$Details'
 ),
        array(
'$match' => array(

   'Details.Model' =>"AUDI",
  'Details.Color' => "RED",
  "Category" =>"Car"
  )
),
  array(
   '$project' => array(


  'Pvalue' => '$Details.Price',
  "Ovalue" =>'$Details.OwnerNameFirst',
 "Cvalue"=>''$Category"
  ),

 )
 ));
```

what i want is to sort `Details.Price` in descending order, also `Catagory` and `Details.OwnerNameFirst` as Select Distinct

Please help

this is the result, value of $result

```
[{"_id":{"$id":"537dbca305a7d12f06000001"},"Pvalue":"60000","Ovalue":"jason","Cvalue":"Car"},{"_id":   {"$id":"537dbca305a7d12f06000001"},"Pvalue":"59000","Ovalue":"george","Cvalue":"Jeep"},{"_id":{"$id":"537dbca305a7d12f06000001"},"Pvalue":"61000","Ovalue":"rahul""Cvalue":"Car"}]
```

Comment: show the output of `$result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems mostly there, but the question is that if we are "grouping" ( which means distinct ) then that implies there are more than one value here for "price".

So which do you want? [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#grp._S_min) [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max) [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last) or [**`$avg`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) ?

I'll use [**`$avg`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) as the example, but replace according to your needs:

```
$result = $collection->aggregate(array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            'Details.Model' =>"AUDI",
            'Details.Color' => "RED",
            "Category" =>"Car"
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$unwind' => '$Details'
    ),
    array(
       '$match' => array(
           'Details.Model' =>"AUDI",
           'Details.Color' => "RED",
           "Category" =>"Car"
       )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                "Ovalue" =>'$Details.OwnerNameFirst',
                "Cvalue"=>''$Category"
            ),
            'Pvalue' => array(
                '$avg' => '$Details.Price'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            'Pvalue' => -1,
        )
    )
));
```

So once you have a value by the distinct keys then you just add a [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage. But pick which of the [group operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) you actually want.

Comment: i got the result, but nothing is displaying in the autocomplete view, i used this query to form an auto complete text box, after this query i also json encoded the result as `json_encode(($result['result']));`

Comment: also i am getting the unique values in console as reponse in firebug of mozilla

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs for [$sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/):

```
$sort: {
    Details.Price: -1
}
```

PHP equivalent:

```
array(
    '$sort' => array("$Details.Price" => -1),
)
```

Check the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/mongocollection.aggregate) for more info.